# auto fill not working in firefox and IE

Tags: java, html, internet-explorer, firefox, autofill

i want my username and password to be autofilled when user already logged into the website, i have enable auto fill by below code. when user visits next time, i want both user name and password field should be prepopulated.

```
<form autocomplete="on">

<input type="text" name="userName" id="userName" autocomplete="on">
<input type="text"  name="paasword" id="password" autocomplete="on">
```

the above code works fine in chrome but this is not working in firefox and ie.

Note - i am using ajax call, when login success i do `window.location.replace(redirect)`

Answer (score 0):

Try this way

```
<form action="" autocomplete="on">
  First name:<input type="text" name="fname"><br>
  Last name: <input type="text" name="lname"><br>

  <input type="submit">
</form>
```

I have tested it [works](http://jsfiddle.net/nvvh2vt7/) in IE and mozilla

IE version 10.0.92

Mozilla firefox version 32.0.1

Comment: i cant have input type as "submit" i am using ajax call. and more over which part i want to change here?

Comment: @pappu_kutty you are using  autocomplete="on" in all the text fields ,remove them

Comment: i did, now working in firefox, but ie is not working

Comment: @pappu_kutty For me its working in both IE and firefox